# nextVal from PostgreSQL sequence in Hibernate fetch sequence multiple times

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, postgresql

For business logic we need to update a record with the next value from a sequence defined directly in database and not in Hibernate (because is not always applied on insert / updates)

For this purpose we have a sequence defined in PostgreSQL witch DDL is:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE public.facturaproveedor_numeracionperiodofiscal_seq
INCREMENT 1 MINVALUE 1
MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807 START 1
CACHE 1;
```

Then in DAO, when some conditions are true, we get the nextVal via:

```
Query query = sesion.createSQLQuery("SELECT nextval('facturaproveedor_numeracionperiodofiscal_seq')");
Long siguiente = ((BigInteger) query.uniqueResult()).longValue();
```

But the values asigned aren't consecutive. Looking the Hibernate output log we see four fetchs to the sequence in the same transaction:

```
Hibernate: SELECT nextval('facturaproveedor_numeracionperiodofiscal_seq') as num
Hibernate: SELECT nextval('facturaproveedor_numeracionperiodofiscal_seq') as num
Hibernate: SELECT nextval('facturaproveedor_numeracionperiodofiscal_seq') as num
Hibernate: SELECT nextval('facturaproveedor_numeracionperiodofiscal_seq') as num
```

Why is this happening? Is this for catching purposes? There is a way to disable this? Or this workaround is not correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hibernate won't usually generate standalone `nextval` calls that look like that, so I won't be too surprised if it's your application doing the multiple fetches. You'll need to collect more tracing information to be sure.

I think you may have a bigger problem though. If you care about sequences skipping values or leaving holes then you're using the wrong tool for the job, you should be using a counter in a table that you `UPDATE`, probably `UPDATE my_id_generator SET id = id + 1 RETURNING id`. This *locks out concurrent transactions* and also ensures that *if the transaction rolls back, the update is undone*.

Sequences by contrast operate in parallel, which means that it's impossible to roll back a sequence increment when a transaction rolls back (see the PostgreSQL documentation). So they're generally not suitable for accounting purposes like invoice numbering and other things where you require a gapless sequence.

---

For other readers who don't have the specific requirement to only sometimes generate a value: don't generate the sequence values manually; use a `@GeneratedValue` annotation.

In Hibernate 3.6 and newer, you should set `hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings` in your Hibernate properties.

Assuming you're mapping a generated key from a PostgreSQL `SERIAL` column, use the mapping:

```
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name="mytable_id_seq",sequenceName="mytable_id_seq", allocationSize=1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="mytable_id_seq")
```

If you omit the `allocationSize` then Hibernate assumes it's bizarre default of `50` and *fails to check that the sequence actually increments by 50* so it tries to insert already-used IDs and fails.

Hibernate/JPA isn't able to automatically create a value for your non-id-properties. The @GeneratedValue annotation is only used in conjunction with @Id to create auto-numbering

Comment: Hibernate/JPA isn't able to automatically create a value for your non-id-properties. The @ GeneratedValue annotation is only used in conjunction with @Id to create auto-numbering

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate caches query results.

Notice the "as num", looks like hibernate is altering the SQL as well.

You should be able to tell Hibernate not to cache results with

```
query.setCacheable(false);
```